# How do I prevent an app from running a foreground service?

Tags: battery-life, permissions

I have an app that wants to run a foreground service (not configurable) but I want the regular Android power restrictions to be applied to it because the foreground service is unnecessary (I always start it manually when needed).

I do not want to force-stop the app.

How can I prevent the app from starting a background service? I tried `pm revoke <packagename> android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE` but apparently that's not a changeable permission type.

Answer (score 3):

This permission is always granted but is managed via AppOps.

To prevent an app from using it, run `appops set <packagename> START_FOREGROUND ignore`.